# Using external class files in a package

Tags: java, package, classpath, javac

I have a program that uses an external library called JHelper located in a neighboring folder

```
home
|--lib
|  |--JHelper.java
|  `--JHelper.class
`--prj
   `--HelloWorld.java
```

The HelloWorld.java file

```
//package prj

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String echoed = JHelper.echo("Hello World");
        System.out.println(echoed);
    }
}
```

I can compile HelloWorld.java with javac by providing JHelper's location in the CLASSPATH like so,

```
PS ~\prj> javac -classpath ".;..\lib\" HelloWorld.java
```

However if I uncomment `package prj` to HelloWorld.java then the javac outputs that it cannot find the symbol `JHelper`

Why does making HelloWorld.java a package prevent javac from finding JHelper on the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a class `A` can only use a class `B` without importing it (or its whole package) if the other class `B` is in the same package as `A` (or is in the `java.lang` package).

But... you can't import classes from the default package.

So the simple rule to follow is: never put classes in the default package.